# Multiple prefix in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.x

IN cakephp 2.x we can configure multiple prefixes in core.php file. like

Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin','blogger'));

But in cake php 3.X the structure of directory has been changed. There is no core.php file, So how we can configure multiple prefix in cakephp 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Route prefixes get defined in the *config/routes.php* file in CakePHP 3 using `Router::prefix()`. So in your case you'd want something like this:-

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
Router::prefix('blogger', function ($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

One other change you need to take into account from CakePHP 2.x to 3.x is that prefixes are mapped to sub-namespaces in your application’s Controller namespace. So for example, if you have a Pages model non-prefixed actions would go in `PagesController` and any actions prefixed `admin` would reside in `Admin/PagesController`.

Checkout the [documentation on routes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) for more details.